# Extract values from a Python list

Tags: python, list, iteration, python-2.x

How can I iterate through and extract values from the following list, the code I am using below only gets the key values.

```
> [{'filename': <docxtpl.InlineImage object at 0x040038D0>, 'desc':
> u'dfgdgfdfg'}, {'filename': <docxtpl.InlineImage object at
> 0x04014930>, 'desc': u'dfgdfgdfg'}, {'filename': <docxtpl.InlineImage
> object at 0x04014A90>, 'desc': u'fghfghfh'}]
```

Code:

```
for k,v in audit_items_list:
    print audit_items_list
    print k
    print v
```

If I use `k.value()`. I get the following error :

```py
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'
```

**Update:**
Thanks for all the help, but i actually want to grab the values of filename and desc on each iteration...

Comment: Is `audit_items_list` a `{}` or `[{}]`? Did you try `iteritems()`?

Comment: You have to iterate twice: over the list and over the dicts inside to print all values.

Comment: list is created using audit_items_list.append({ 'desc' : kwargs["audit_d_pc_{}".format(i)], 'filename' :  photo_embed})

Answer (score 2):

The outer item is a list, and the inner items are dictionaries. You just need to go one level deeper.

```python
for audit_item in audit_items_list:
  for k, v in audit_item.items():
    # iterate over key value pairs. 
    # Or get the entire list of each by doing item.keys() or item.values()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `audit_items_list.items()` if you are using Python 3 or `audit_items_list.iteritems()` if you are using Python 2.

Comment: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Comment: `audit_items_list` is a list.

Answer (score 1):

```
for tdict in audit_items_list:    # To iterate over all dictionaries present in the list
    # print tdict
    for key in tdict:    # To iterate over all the keys in current dictionary
        # print key
        print tdict[key]    # To get the value corresponding to that key
```

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, this is a list of dictionaries where every dictionary has one key-value pair.

```
for item in audit_items_list:
 (key, val) = item.items()
  print(key,value)
```

Hope this helps!